# can't read data from jsp server

Tags: java, android, database, jsp

I made android application which can read specific db from jsp server.
for example, there are various database table on server such as time, temperature, humidity...etc. and I like to show time and temperature on application. I tried a lot and Server shows proper values but it always shows "Fail to read temp values". 
here is my code.

UserFunctions.java

```
public class UserFunctions {

private static String readURL = "http://myip:8080/read.do";
public String read_email;
ArrayList   tempList    = new ArrayList( ); 
tempVO      vo      = null;

public boolean read_flag = false;

public boolean list_read_flag = false;
public boolean list_date_flag = false;

public class HttpFunctions {


     public ArrayList readTemp(String email)
     {
          r_flag = false;

          read_email = email;

          new ReadHttpTask().execute();
          while(!read_flag);
          return tempList;

}

class ReadHttpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(readURL);

            Vector<NameValuePair> nameValue = new Vector<NameValuePair>();
            nameValue.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", input_email));

            HttpEntity enty = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValue, HTTP.UTF_8);
            request.setEntity(enty);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse res = client.execute(request);
            //get a value from server
            HttpEntity entityResponse = res.getEntity();


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res.getEntity().getContent(),"utf-8"));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String str;


            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null){ 
                if( str!=null && str.length() > 6 )
                {
                    if (str.substring(0, 2).equals("data")) {
                        vo = new tempVO();
                    }   

                    if (str.substring(0, 5).equals("read:")) {

                        vo.setDATA      ( str.substring(6, str.length()) );
                        list_read_flag = true;
                    }

                    if (str.substring(0, 5).equals("date:")) {

                        vo.setDATA_DATE ( str.substring(6, str.length()) );

                        list_date_flag = true;
                    }
                    if(list_read_flag && list_date_flag)
                    {
                        dataList.add(vo);

                        list_date_flag = false;
                        list_read_flag = false;

                    }
                }
            }

            read_flag = true;

        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


   TextView     txtView;
   ArrayList    tempList    = new ArrayList( ); 

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.temp);

    txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.readtempdate);
    txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.readtemp);



    Bundle intentRead = getIntent().getExtras();
    String read_email = intentRead.getString("email");

    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

    tempList = userFunction.readtemp(read_email);

    if(tempList.isEmpty())
        {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to read temp values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    if( tempList!=null && tempList.size() > 0 ) 
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++ ) 
        {
            tempVO tempvo = (tempVO)tempList.get(i);
            txtView.append(tempvo.gettempDATA());
            txtView.append(tempvo.gettempDATA_DATE());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `but it always shows "Fail to read temp values"`. That is a wrong description of your problem as it is you who is displaying that Toast. You display that message when `tempList.isEmpty()`. So you should have told us that your list is always empty.

Comment: `while(!read_flag);`. That is very bad coding. Although you use an AsyncTask to not block the gui thread you will still block the gui thread by that statement. You should implement and use onPostExecute of the AsyncTask to continue with the results of doInBackground.

Comment: Of course tempList is always empty. You are never adding anything to it. I see a `dataList.add(vo);`. But dataList is nowhere defined.

Comment: @greenapps yes I checked logcat and it shows that tempList is empty..please explain me more please

Comment: You are not logging anything so please show what the logcat shows about an empty tempList. And further i already told you why tempList is empty. And further you did not react on my comment about dataList.